# Angular js full calendar - Events loaded from database do not fit nicely into calendar

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, fullcalendar

We are using `events` in `fullCalendar` to load the events from a database, but the data is not fitting nicely to the calendar. This is the print screen:

[image]

**Code below**

```
/* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent) {
            if (calEvent.url) {
                window.open(calEvent.url, "_blank");
                return false;
            } else {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:', calEvent.title, {
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: true,
                        Cancel: false
                    }
                });

                if (title) {
                    //user type something and click OK
                    calEvent.title = title;
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
                    //update event to DB
                    vm.submitCalendarItem(calEvent.title, calEvent.start, calEvent.id);

                } else if (title === '') {
                    //user click OK, but input field empty
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);

                    //delete event
                    vm.deleteCalendarItem(calEvent.id);

                } else {
                    //user click cancel
                }
            }
        },

        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: 'month',
            right: 'prev,next today'
        },

        height: 350,
        editable: true,
        firstDay: 1, //  1(Monday) this can be changed to 0(Sunday) for the USA system
        selectable: true,
        defaultView: 'month',
        axisFormat: 'h:mm',

        columnFormat: {
            month: 'ddd',    // Mon
            week: 'ddd d', // Mon 7
            day: 'dddd M/d',  // Monday 9/7
            agendaDay: 'dddd d'
        },

        titleFormat: {
            month: 'MMMM yyyy', // September 2009
            week: "MMMM yyyy", // September 2009
            day: 'MMMM yyyy'                  // Tuesday, Sep 8, 2009
        },

        allDaySlot: false,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );

                //submit new event to DB
                vm.submitCalendarItem(title, start, '');
            }

            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        disableDragging: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }
        },

        viewRender: function (view, element) {
            var selectedDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
            vm.SelectedYear = selectedDate.getFullYear();
            vm.SelectedMonth = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1;
        },
        events: function (start, end, callback) {
            $.getJSON("/Dashboard/GetCalenderItemsList?month=" + vm.SelectedMonth + "&year=" + vm.SelectedYear + "", function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    vm.DashboardItemsList = [];
                    vm.MappedDashboardItemsList = [];
                    vm.DashboardItemsList = response.CalendarItems
                } else {
                    alert(response.responseMsg);
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < vm.DashboardItemsList.length; i++) {
                    if (vm.DashboardItemsList[i]) {
                        var startDate = new Date(parseInt(vm.DashboardItemsList[i].EventDate.substr(6)));
                        if (vm.DashboardItemsList[i].Link == null) {
                            var dashboardObj = {
                                id: vm.DashboardItemsList[i].CalendarItemId,
                                title: vm.DashboardItemsList[i].Text,
                                start: new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), (startDate.getMonth()), startDate.getDate()),
                                url: ''

                            }

                            vm.MappedDashboardItemsList.push(dashboardObj);

                        } else {
                            var dashboardObj = {
                                id: vm.DashboardItemsList[i].CalendarItemId,
                                title: vm.DashboardItemsList[i].Text,
                                start: new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), (startDate.getMonth()), startDate.getDate()),
                                url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/' + vm.DashboardItemsList[i].Link
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                callback(vm.MappedDashboardItemsList);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: "Using viewRender in fullCalendar to load the events,"...that's your first mistake. That's not how you use fullCalendar. Refer to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function to see how to properly load your events.

Comment: if things are flickering, it possibly indicates some kind of infinite loop - do some console logging or debugging in the browser's developer tools to check what's happening. Using viewRender to create events always runs the risk that it might re-run viewRender after you've added your events (which then tries to add the events again, and so on forever) - there are some circumstances in which that can happen. Use one of the proper documented ways to load events and you'll avoid this risk.

Comment: if things aren't "fitting nicely" (which seems to be a separate problem, as far as I can tell), then check that your custom CSS hasn't screwed something up - go back to the fullCalendar default CSS and see if you still have an issue.

Comment: @ADyson I have tried to load my events followed the reference URL you show me. Not referring to any custom CSS, but still having the same issue. Events are not fit properly to the calendar. I did testing by harcoding the events data, then it will fit nicely to the calendar.

Comment: @ADyson, I found the flickering issue is because i use **$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');**

Is there any method after ajax get the events data from database, then I can ask the calendar to do the resize again?

Comment: After I have clicked "next" button to next month and clicked "previous" button again to previous month, then all events are fitting nicely to the calendar

Comment: you clearly have some custom CSS, based on your screenshot - those colours don't come by default, for a start

Comment: And why do you think you need to ask the calendar to resize itself? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: Also can you please update your question now with the new way you are calling the events, that would help a lot - thanks. In fact please show all of your fullCalendar setup code.

Comment: @ADyson, I have already updated my code. This is the reference to which I'm referring to.

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/calendar-design

Comment: "already updated", no I posted my comment nearly an hour ago, you only updated your question 15 minutes ago.

Comment: Anyway, that snippet is using fullCalendar 1.6.4 which is a long time out of support. Firstly please update to a supported version and see if you still have a problem. The current version is 3.9.0.